# Installing a dev version of Vagrant but bundler doesn't seem to be installing the vagrant gem from source

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, vagrant

I am trying to get a hackable installation of vagrant working on my machine. It uses bundler, and in its Gemspec it refers to the remote "." to add itself as a gem. The bundle install command seems to be working, but  the "vagrant" gem doesn't seem to appear in gem list:

```
alexandma@ALEXANDMA-1-MBP ~/Projects/vagrant_ (master)
bundle install | grep "vagrant "
Using vagrant 1.6.4.dev from source at .
alexandma@ALEXANDMA-1-MBP ~/Projects/vagrant_ (master)
gem list | grep -c vagrant
0
```

Answer (score 2):

Installing a gem from a file path or Git repository with Bundler will not install an actual gem file that can be seen by the `gem` command. Only Bundler is aware of the gem, so you'll need to run Bundler-aware commands to use it. In this case, running `bundle list` will show the entire list of dependencies including the line you see from the output of `bundle install` (Using vagrant 1.6.4.dev from source at .). To invoke the bundled version of Vagrant, you'll need to run `bundle exec vagrant`.